# Adding click handler to a dynamically generated content. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Json format is as follows:

```
[{"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"},
{"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"},
{"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"},
{"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"}]
```

I also have a jquery script in which I'm adding dinamically hyperlinks:

```
$.ajax({
  url: './download.php', 
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  dataType:'text',
  success: function(ans)
  {
    var data = JSON.parse(ans);

    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        $('links').append('<li><a><div>' + v.Text + '<span class="small">' + v.DateTime+ '</span></div></a></li>');

    });     

    }});
```

I want a simple effect - a list of hyperlinks on my webpage. When user cliks any hyperlink, he will see an alert window with the value of the field `id`, `Color`, `DateTime` and `Text`.

I tried adding a function inside $.each:

```
$.find('a').click(function(){
    alert(v.Color+v.id+v.Date+v.Text);
})
```

But it tells me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.find(...).click is not a function
```

So how can I append a function (click handler) to each generated link that will be displaying all properties related to the clicked link?

Comment: Are you sure you `jQuery` code is working? `links` tag does not exist. You probably want to retrieve an id here (i.e. `$('#links')` instead). I don't think you are actually inserting any link in your page. That maybe the reason why you can't append a `click` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problems here:

1. `$.find('a')` is not going to work. You need to select a dom element first on which you will apply the selector (e.g. `$(document).find('a')`).
2. You are appending the `li`s to an element selected using `$('links')`. This is not going to work either. This syntaxe selects tag. There is no HTML tags `<links>`. I guess what you are actually trying to do is to select the dom element with the id "links". To do so you need to do `$('#links')`.

Here is a working snippet.

```js
var data = [
  {"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"},
  {"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"},
  {"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"},
  {"id":"1","Text":"esj","DateTime":"2015-10-21 19:00:00", "Color":"Red"}
];


$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  // Create the li.
  var li = $('<li><a href="#"><div>' + v.Text + '<span class="small">' + v.DateTime + '</span></div></a></li>');

  // Append it to the dom element with the id "links".
  $('#links').append(li);

  // Attach the click handler to its <a> child.
  var a = li.find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(v.Color + " " + v.id + " " + v.DateTime + " " + v.Text);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! But is there a way of making <a> tag more like... a hyperlink look, with a specific coursor pointer when user highlights it for example?

Comment: You need to add an href. Preferably the anchor tag: `href="#"`. See my edit.

Comment: Or you can also just rewrite the css. See here for more info on this issue (don't follow the first answer, I know it has many votes but it is a bad one): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 1):

Try [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#links').on('click', 'a', function() {
    alert('message');
});
```

Comment: From the linked docs page: As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method.

Comment: True, @Andy. I'm always confused about which is the new one: delegate/on, fail/error, and success/done. =) Updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways of doing this.

One is to add a `click` handler on each `<li>` that you add...

```
var $li = $('<li><a><div>' + v.Text + '<span class="small">' + v.DateTime+ '</span></div></a></li>');
$('#links').append($li);
$li.click(function(){
    alert(v.Color+v.id+v.DateTime+v.Text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/t38x715g/

Another is to bind the handler to your `links` element, and use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a selector. You'll need to keep track of the data you want to show though - you could use [`$.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for that.

```
$('#links').on('click','a',function(){
    var $li = $(this).parents('li');                
    alert($li.data('Color')+''+$li.data('id')+''+$li.data('DateTime')+''+$li.data('Text'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/t38x715g/2/